# Compact topology between box and product topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness, infinite-product

Suppose we have a family $(X_i)_i$ of compact $T_1$, but not necessarily Hausdorff spaces.

Suppose $\tau$ is a topology on $\prod_i X_i$ which is compact, refines the product topology, and is refined by the box topology.

Can $\tau$ be distinct from the product topology?

Note that if $X_i$ are all Hausdorff, then the answer is no, even if we don't assume that the box topology is finer.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.3665&ved=2ahUKEwiukayElsraAhXFIJAKHfP5D_IQFjAFegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1ZUf3xA_nV8sMsy31S-S5E) might be useful $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  For instance, let us consider the product $X=Y^\mathbb{N}$, where $Y$ denotes $\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology.  Let $A\subset X$ be the set of all constant sequences.  Note that in the product topology, $A$ has the cofinite topology, and in particular is compact.  However, $A$ is not closed in the product topology.  On the other hand, $A$ is closed in the box topology: if $s\in X$ is a nonconstant sequence, then by a simple diagonalization you can construct a box-open neighborhood of $s$ which contains no constant sequences.

So now, let $\tau$ be the topology on $X$ generated by the product topology and the set $X\setminus A$.  Since $A$ is compact in the product topology, $\tau$ will still be compact.  Since $A$ is closed in the box topology, $\tau$ is contained in the box topology.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, it is worth adding that $A$ is actually dense in $X$ (the sequence $a_n=(n,n,n,\ldots)$ of constant sequences converges to every point in $X$). The diagonalization procedure is not that obvious to me: you have to consider two cases, one when there is a value which occurs infinitely many times, and the other when every value occurs only finitely many times. With that observation, that is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

One way to construct such topologies is described in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.3665.pdf): we take a (potentially trivial) filter $\mathcal{F}$ on the index set $I$, (we have a family $X_i, i \in I$), and define a base for $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ by all sets $\prod_{i \in I} U_i$, where $U_i$ is open in $X_i$ for all $i \in I$, and the set $\{i \in I: U_i = X_i\} \in \mathcal{F}$.

It's easy to check (and the paper does) that this is indeed a base for a topology $\mathcal{T}(X_i, I, \mathcal{F})$ on $\prod_i X_i$.

Clearly if $\mathcal{G}$ is another filter on $I$ such that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$, then $\mathcal{T}(X_i, I, \mathcal{F}) \subseteq \mathcal{T}(X_i, I, \mathcal{G})$, so finer filters give finer topologies.

The product topology is exactly the case where $\mathcal{F}$ is the cofinite filter on $I$, and the box-topology is where $\mathcal{F}$ is the powerset of $I$ (the trivial filter). So taking any filter inbetween those gives a topology that's inbetween as well. We then also get topologies that make the projections open and continuous etc., and such that products of Hausdorff spaces are still Hausdorff,etc. Nice properties (like preserving compactness, connectedness etc.) are probably out, in most cases.

Comment: Well, but how do you guarantee that the intermediate topology is compact?

Comment: @tomasz you cannot, the only way you get guaranteed compactness is when you use the cofinite filter, so the product topology.

Comment: But the point of my question was to assume that the intermediate topology is compact.